# Android Studio App Run Error

Tags: android-studio

everytime I run my app, it gives me an error saying:
Failed to find: com.google.android.gsm:play-services:4.2.42

do I have to install the services from SDK? since I failed to find them

or should I remove the compiling of this line of code

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar])
    compile 'com.google.android.gsm:play-services:4.2.42'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
```

NOTE: I'm new to Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have this in you Android SDK directory

```
ANDROID_SK_DIR\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services
```

with a directory name 4.2.42 there.

If its not there, then you are correct you have to install "Google Repository" Listed in

```
SDK Manager > Extras
```